# get data from previous sheets

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

Can you guys help me out? I think i'm kind of stuck with the code below. I almost got the code that I wanted but at the end it does not do the thing I like.

```
Dim acs, cos, as_col, as_row As Integer

     cos = Sheets.Count
     acs = ActiveSheet.Index

     as_LRow = Sheets(acs).Cells(Sheets(acs).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     For as_row = 3 To as_LRow
        std_number = Sheets(acs).Cells(as_row, 1).Value 

        earliersheets = acs - 1 

        For s = 1 To earliersheets
             ilast_row = Sheets(s).Cells(Sheets(s).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
             For r = 3 To ilast_row
                std_number_new = Sheets(s).Cells(r, 1).Value

                If std_number = std_number_new Then
                    a = a & Sheets(s).Cells(r, 6).Value
                    'Sheets(acs).Cells(as_row, 8).Value = Sheets(s).Cells(r, 8).Value
                    Sheets(acs).Cells(as_row, 8).Value = Sheets(acs).Cells(as_row, 6).Value & " + " & a

                End If
                a = ""
             Next r

        Next s

     Next as_row
```

What I want is:
After adding, manually, a new sheet I want to press on a button. This button activates the code above. What I want is to check a value in a particulaire cell in column "A". If the value in this column matches with the value from previous sheet then display the value in the sixth column in the newly added sheet. The code above does that, but it works only for two sheets. If I make more then two sheets it does not display more values then two.

**Update**
I added my file in the link: [Check.xlsm](http://ge.tt/6EKKUmf2)
After opening this file clear the H-column in the third (and maybe the second sheet) then run the macro within. You'll see what I mean
[image]

All I want is to get all the previous values in previous sheet displaced in column-H. For example I marked two cells with values, these values get displayed in the H-column after running the macro.

Comment: Are you trying to update column 6?  Your code is placing the new value in column 8.   (`Sheets(acs).Cells(as_row, 8).Value = Sheets(acs).Cells(as_row, 6).Value & " + " & a` is placing into column 8 the value that is in column 6 of the new sheet, appended with " + " and the value from whatever prior sheet is being processed.  Therefore, if `std_number` is found in multiple prior sheets, only the last of those values is being appended to the value in column 6 of the new sheet and placed in column 8.)

Comment: Help,  see the update

Comment: Nope.  No way.  I am **not** going to follow a link to a 3rd party site.  (Apart from the obvious security issues, it means that future users of the site won't be able to see the question in its entirety because all they will probably come across is a broken link.)  If you want us to see what you mean, please paste an image into your question.  (And I already know what your code **does** because you posted the code into your question, I just need more info about what you **want** it to do - e.g. are you wanting to update column 8/H or column 6/F?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that you were always storing in column H a value created by taking the value from column F of the current sheet and appending the value from column F of the sheet being processed within the loop.  When you move to the next sheet within the loop, you're replacing the previous value with a new value.

So, when processing sheet w3-6, you first look at sheet w1-4 and generate a value of "13 + 34" and store that in sheet w3-6's cell H3.  Then you look at sheet w2-5 and generate a value of "13 + 18" and replace the value of "13 + 34" currently in sheet w3-6's cell H3 with the value of "13 + 18".

Try this code instead:

```
Dim acs As Long, cos As Long, as_col As Long, as_row As Long
Dim s As Long
Dim as_LRow As Long
Dim ilast_row As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim a As String

cos = Sheets.Count
acs = ActiveSheet.Index

as_LRow = Sheets(acs).Cells(Sheets(acs).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For as_row = 3 To as_LRow
    std_number = Sheets(acs).Cells(as_row, 1).Value 

    'Initialise variable containing result to go into column H
    a = Sheets(acs).Cells(as_row, 6).Value

    'Process earlier sheets in reverse order
    '(so that values will be shown in reverse order)
    For s = acs - 1 To 1 Step -1
        ilast_row = Sheets(s).Cells(Sheets(s).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
        For r = 3 To ilast_row
            std_number_new = Sheets(s).Cells(r, 1).Value

            If std_number = std_number_new Then
                'Append value to result string
                a = a & " + " & Cstr(Sheets(s).Cells(r, 6).Value)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r

    Next s

    'Store result
    Sheets(acs).Cells(as_row, 8).Value = a
Next as_row
```

Comment: Thanks mate,I am gonna check this out.